# Change the length of median line of boxplot in MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

The figure above is one screenshot from the paper. To achieve a similar style, I used matplotlib.

```
bp = plt.boxplot(data,sym='',widths=0.75, patch_artist=True)

for median in bp['medians']:
    median.set(color='k', linewidth=1.5,)
```

But I can't set **a second short-line in the median position**.

Is there any easy way to deal with the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain the coordinates of the median line and use them to plot an additional line, with higher linewidth but only half as long as the original line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(2)
data = np.random.normal(loc=3., size=(100,5))

bp = plt.boxplot(data,sym='',widths=0.75, patch_artist=True)

for median in bp['medians']:
    median.set(color='k', linewidth=1.5,)
    x,y = median.get_data()
    xn = (x-(x.sum()/2.))*0.5+(x.sum()/2.)
    plt.plot(xn, y, color="k", linewidth=10, solid_capstyle="butt", zorder=4)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Mind the parameters `solid_capstyle="butt", zorder=4` which make sure that the line in in the foreground and that it has no cap extention.